# Web server calls back to web browser client machanisms in ASP.NET

Tags: .net, asp.net, callback, webserver, webclient

**Purpose:**

I want to implement a machanism by which web server can make call back to web browser client.

**Problem Description:**

I have a project where web browser client sends web request to web server, which takes a long time to process the request, and return the result.

**Tentative Solution:**

Is it possible that the web server can make a call back to web browser client, and send data to brower cleint.

**Other possible Solution**

1. Web browser client polling:

Downside: polling method is only considered as last resort.

2 Server Side AJAX JavaScript (if exist)

Custom server side javascipt that can talk to .net, and call web browser client javascript.

Thanks

Comment: What you are describing sounds a lot like the concept of [Comet](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comet_(programming)).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are currently 2 solutions for this:

- [WebSockets](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WebSockets) provide a true callback, but are not widely adopted
- Use a [Comet](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comet_%28programming%29) implementation (such as [WebSync](http://www.frozenmountain.com/websync/))

Comment: thank you for your advice, I am half way reading them. But I think they are cool. I wonder if you are ware of any code example for this. The ajax model provides callback to web client browser, I wonder if we should research into this area. Again, those articles are definitely helpful.

Comment: I think this could be updated, WebSockets are basically available everywhere now.

Answer (score 1):

There isn't a true "callback" mechanism when dealing with web browswers as clients.  Here is a link to a similar problem and potential solution.

[Async method in asp.net web service](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6052199/async-method-in-asp-net-web-service/6060315#6060315)

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, HTTP doesn't work that way. It's a client/server, request/response protocol. You need to revisit your requirements.

The best you can do is have the browser poll the server by making requests which just respond with an "empty" answer until the server is ready to "call back".